# How to specify android assembled library file name on gradle 5.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Gradle changed it's behavior when I updated from 5.0 to 5.1.

Lets assume that we have an android project with single module named **library**.
On Gradle 5.0 (and previous versions) when I executed `./gradlew assembleRelease` or `./gradlew assembleDebug` generated output was `library-release.aar` or `library-debug.aar` respectively.

After I updated to Gradle 5.1 (I also tried 5.1.1) it generates only `library.aar` for any build type without any build-type classifier in output file name.

So my question is: how can I force Gradle 5.1 to set correct output file naming for different build types like it was before? Below is my library module's build.gradle.kts, but I doesn't think that there is something wrong with it:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("maven-publish")
}

val libraryVersion = "1.5.0"

android {
    compileSdkVersion(28)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(16)
        targetSdkVersion(28)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = libraryVersion
    }

    lintOptions {
        isAbortOnError = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("include" to listOf("*.jar"), "dir" to "libs")))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If I add a following code to build.gradle.kts:

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.libraryVariants.forEach { libraryVariant ->
        libraryVariant.outputs.forEach { output ->
            println(output.outputFile.name)
        }
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
library-debug.aar
library-release.aar
```

Now it starts looking like a bug in gradle 5.1

Comment: it does have an open issue, upvote it please https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8328

Comment: @Majkeee I've opened that issue. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as we can see in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8328, it is a bug which is fixed in Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.

Comment: Which will be fixed in 3.4 and, maybe, in 3.3.x. Both of them are not released yet.

Comment: That issue is now marked as resolved but I'm using 3.5.0-alpha09 with Gradle 5.3.1 and renaming the AAR file is not working. It has always been irritating that naming the final artifact is not easier with the Android Gradle Plugin!

Answer (score 1):

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def filePrefix = "$buildDir/outputs/aar/$archivesBaseName"
        outputFileName = "${archivesBaseName}-${version}.aar"
        def fileSuffix = "aar"
        def originalFile = file("$filePrefix-${variant.buildType.name}.$fileSuffix")
        def renamedFile = "$filePrefix-${variant.buildType.name}-$version.$fileSuffix"
        tasks.named("assemble").configure {
            doLast {
                originalFile.renameTo(renamedFile)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `archivesBaseName` and `version` can defined in default block of libraries build.gradle